# Can Google cloud shell run Python3

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-signin, google-oauth

I have previously had the [Credential Management Server](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/credential-management-api/#1) running. When I tried to get it running today I got an error saying Python3 is not supported: -

```
ERROR: Python 3 and later is not compatible with the Google Cloud SDK.
Please use Python version 2.7.x.

If you have a compatible Python interpreter installed, you can use it by setting

the CLOUDSDK_PYTHON environment variable to point to it.
```

So I entered the following command: -

```
export CLOUDSDK_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python
```

and rebuilt the environment and restarted the server. Now when I try to access the server it looks like I'm getting an error on the Python 3 version of "print".

Q1. Is the Google Cloud Shell Python exaample only compatible with Python3

Q2. Can I get the Python 3 version to run correctly under this environment

```
ERROR    2018-10-01 04:36:24,384 wsgi.py:263]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/google/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 240, in Handle
    handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
  File "/google/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 299, in _LoadHandler
    handler, path, err = LoadObject(self._handler)
  File "/google/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 85, in LoadObject
    obj = __import__(path[0])
  File "/home/maherrj/credential-management-api/working/main.py", line 28, in <module>
    from oauth2client import client
  File "/home/maherrj/credential-management-api/working/lib/oauth2client/client.py", line 39, in <module>
    from oauth2client import transport
  File "/home/maherrj/credential-management-api/working/lib/oauth2client/transport.py", line 17, in <module>
    import httplib2
  File "/home/maherrj/credential-management-api/working/lib/httplib2/__init__.py", line 382
    print('%s:' % h, end=' ', file=self._fp)
                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are mixing some concepts:

- Cloud Shell != Credential Management API. The first one is [an interactive shell environment](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/features), with some tools, like Python 2, 3, Maven, etc, already installed. The second one is, as the name says, an API for managing credentials in applications.
- The code that you mention uses Python 2.7, demonstrated by several things. The main one is the [`app.yaml`](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/credential-management-api/blob/master/app.yaml) file that is used, which explicitly mentions using that version.

So, you would have to port that code to Python 3, if possible, or keep using Python 2.7.

Comment: Not my code $ git clone https://github.com/googlecodelabs/credential-management-api.git yes should be 2.7 but as I mentioned it fails because it uses the Python3 Print function format